# Can windows phone 7 microphone detect frequencies in the range of 18k-19kHz?

Tags: windows-phone-7, microphone, frequency

Can the windows phone 7 in-built microphone detect frequencies higher than 18kHz?

Comment: Why would software have a microphone?

Comment: Ignacio, MS nailed down most hardware specs for WP7 so it isn't that strange a question. But I'm not sure if the mike is specified in this much detail.

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, the API supports recording PCM with sufficient quality to express a 18kHz sine wave.  Standard POTS lines and even T1 lines generally operate at 8 kHz 16 bit which is mathematically enough to correctly record a max of 4 kHz.  And since the mic isn't usually used for anything higher quality than telephony audio, I bet the limiting factor will be the hardware... your mileage will definitely vary from phone to phone.