# How to capture ultrasonic sounds using windows phone 7 microphone

Tags: windows-phone-7

There is requirement for me to capture the ultrasonic sound emitted continuosly by a speaker by using windows phone 7...The

sample rate of windows phone 7 is set to 16000 hz by default...Is there any library avilable for the same...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114573/can-windows-phone-7-microphone-detect-frequencies-in-the-range-of-18k-19khz

Answer (score 0):

The physical mic cannot detect those high frequencies efficiently.....

Comment: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2007651/Batphone-app-captures-ultrasonic-calls-winged-creatures-nearby.html  Read the page carefully they have a external ultrasonic mic.....